# iTerm2 pin Visor (hotkey) window

Tags: iterm2, iterm

Is there anyway to pin (keep on top) the Visor / hotkey window for iTerm2?

Every time I give focus to another window (e.g. Chrome for documentation), iTerm2's hotkey window disappears.  I have to invoke the hotkey again in order to start typing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have version 3.0.0 or later (or pre-release versions). If you go to the "Keys" tab in iTerm2's preferences, you should see the "Hotkey window hides when focus is lost" checkbox in the "Hotkey" section. Uncheck it.

Comment: thanks @epimorphic. The nightly build looks awesome - heaps of new features like tab shortcut keys! :D

Answer (score 5):

In 3.1.beta.5, it's under "Profiles", and then click "Configure Hotkey Window for the "Visor" profile you want to pin.
[image]